# Trino helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, catalog, trino

Am new to trino. Tried installing trino on kubernetes using the helm chart available under trinodb/charts.

Coordinator and worker pods come up fine, but am unable to find catalog location. Checked the helm chart and it seems to not have it defined anywhere either.

How did others who used the helm chart define new connectors and use.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 3):

They added catalogs in their chart, have a look at this pull request https://github.com/trinodb/charts/pull/1

Answer (score 2):

I found some interesting tips in the Trino slack channel. I am quoting Karthik below:

> There are two options
>
> 1. creating catalog files using config maps, if you take this route then when ever you need to add new catalogs you need to rebuild your images.
> 2. create a persistent volume and attach the volume to docker container, this PV can be anything (NFS, S3 etc) and store catalogs here, so when you add catalogs you just need to restart the server but no need to rebuild the image

I am new to Kubernetes deployments and will be experimenting with the aforementioned approach.

Comment: Did #2 work. If so did you just update the deployment? Also how do you mount it to `/etc/trino/catalogs/` without overwriting what's there as part of the base image. Not concerned about the catalogs perse but like in docker if i mount the hostpath volume to say something like /etc/trino/plugins then I'm concerned that the existing plugins would be lost